# Missing rows at top of worksheet in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet and I only see from the 49<sup>th</sup> row onwards. I try to go up but the scrollbar doesn't work.

If I use the up arrow key I can see the rows change, but I cannot see it in the spreadsheet.

What should I do?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

Fixed. I simply had the row 49 frozen. I unfroze and refroze the row 1.